# Как сделать чтобы цель яндекс метрике срабатывала только при успешной отправки формы?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, yandex-metrika-api

Добрый день! Есть следующий код формы:

```html
<?
echo $warnText ? "<div class='warnText'>$warnText</div>" : NULL;
$res = $db->get_var("SELECT CustomSettings FROM Sub_Class WHERE Sub_Class_ID=$cc");
( $res ? eval("\$cc_settings = $res") : $cc_settings = NULL );
$res = $db->get_var("SELECT CustomSettingsTemplate FROM Class WHERE Class_ID=$classID");
eval("\$default_cc_settings = $res");
if (!$inside_admin) {
    ?> <p /> <?
    echo ( $cc_settings['TextBefore'] ? $cc_settings['TextBefore'] : $default_cc_settings[TextBefore][default_value] );
    ?>
    <style type='text/css'>
        div.textarea { width: 100%; }
    </style>

    <div class='nc_full nc_mail_from_site'>
        <form name='adminForm'  onsubmit="yaCounter12924709.reachGoal('ORDER-CONTACTS'); return true;" method='post' action='<? echo $SUB_FOLDER.$HTTP_ROOT_PATH ?>add.php'>
    <? $nc_core->token->get_input() ?>
            <input name='cc' type='hidden' value='<? echo $cc ?>'>
            <input name='sub' type='hidden' value='<? echo $sub ?>'>
            <input name='catalogue' type='hidden' value='<? echo $catalogue ?>'>
            <input type='hidden' name='posting' value='1'>

            <div class='nc_item'>
                <?= nc_string_field("Name", "maxlength='55' size='10'", $classID, 1); ?>
            </div> <br />
            
            <div class='nc_item'>
                <?= nc_string_field("Phone", "maxlength='55' size='10'", $classID, 1); ?>
            </div> <br />

            <div class='nc_item'>
                <?= nc_string_field("Email", "maxlength='55' size='10'", $classID, 1); ?>
            </div> <br />

            <div class='nc_item'>
                <?= nc_string_field("Subject", "maxlength='55' size='10'", $classID, 1); ?>
            </div> <br />

            <div class='nc_item'>
                <?= nc_text_field("Text", "style='width: 100%;'", $classID, 1); ?>
            </div>

            <div class='nc_description'>
                Звездочкой (*) отмечены поля, обязательные для заполнения.
            </div> <br />
            <div class='nc_submit'><input  value='Отправить' type='submit' /></div>
        </form>
    </div>
<? } ?>
```

Как сделать чтобы цель срабатывала при нажатии на кнопку только после успешной отправки формы и отображалась в консоли Reach goal?

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте!
Скорее всего вы используете Netcat как CMS.
Вам нужно в результате успешной отправки выполнить код Javascript.
То есть, узнаете что отправка успешна, по результатам отправки на сервер, в обработчике на onsubmit и после этого выполняете код Метрики, нужные данные после успешной отправки можно отредактировать здесь -  Разработка / Компоненты / Ваш компонент формы / Шаблоны действий / Действие после добавления объекта.

Comment: Вы можете написать примерную реализацию этого? Я в данной теме не очень хорошо разбираюсь

Comment: Для начала, перехватывайте все отправки формы.
Проще всего через jQuery:

https://gist.github.com/mitkinstas/e25ef1b18ec191ff249e1dcd7c0eb3a4

Ну и изменения в компоненте в Netcat тоже нужно сделать, чтобы в случае успешной отправки приходил `success`.

Comment: Stanislav данный код не срабатывает для моей формы Reach goal не отображается в консоли. В чем может быть причина? Данный код указал в Разработка / Компоненты / Ваш компонент формы / Шаблоны действий / Действие после добавления объекта.

Comment: Код который я привел  тут - gist.github.com/mitkinstas/e25ef1b18ec191ff249e1dcd7c0eb3a4  Пример перехвата отправки формы. Зайди на форум вашей CMS и узнайте о там как настроить ее.